# Prefetch in Nuxt.js/Vue.js inside a method (Prefetch next page after form completion)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there a way to prefetch a page in a component's method?  For example, to be able to prefetch this next page in a method:

`this.$router.push('next-page')`

I want to prefetch the next page after a form is submitted.

(I am using Nuxt.js)

Comment: what do you mean prefetch, the pages are out of the box server side rendered

Comment: My understanding is that if I was to use ```<nuxt-link to="next-page">```, that page would be prefetched so it should load instantly when someone clicks the link. That is the behavior I want to replicate in my method.